# how to make a single list out of this lists of lists , using list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

**how to do this in a single line.**

```
   b=[['1','2','3','4','5'],['11','12','13','14','15'],['6','7','8','9','10']]
   c=[]
   for x in b:
        for y in x:
            c.append(int(y))
   c.sort()
   print(c)
```

expected output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> b=[['1','2','3','4','5'],['11','12','13','14','15'],['6','7','8','9','10']]
>>> sorted(int(j) for i in b for j in i)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Comment: 1UP: Neat solution, no imports required.

Comment: My +1.  The only thing that I do not like is to use the `l` identifier ;)

Comment: @pepr I changed it to use the conventional `i` and `j` to iterate through now.

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools
c = sorted(int(a) for a in itertools.chain(*b))
```

or, as @jamylak correctly noted:

```
import itertools
c = sorted(int(a) for a in itertools.chain.from_iterable(b))
```

using `map` is a little bit faster (and faster than the double list comprehension in @jamylak's answer):

```
import itertools
c = sorted(map(int, itertools.chain.from_iterable(b)))
```

Comment: Oh, heck. I forgot about `itertools`. ;)

Comment: Why does nobody like `chain.from_iterable`?

Comment: @eumiro this is faser than jamylak's answer?

Comment: @user1374499 - not really. In this case, it is 6 percent slower.

Comment: @user1374499 - using `map(int…` makes it faster than his answer.

Comment: worked fine but I guess as I don't know `itertools`, the solution is not much clear to me.

Comment: @jamylak: Probably because it's so damn verbose if you use the fully-qualified name: `itertools.chain.from_iterable`

Comment: @NiklasB I always thought it should be called `chain.from_iter` instead. Even though that isn't that much shorter it still seems much better and it is consistent with the python `builtin` called `iter`.

Answer (score 2):

Another variation

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> b=[['1','2','3','4','5'],['11','12','13','14','15'],['6','7','8','9','10']]
>>> sorted(chain(*b),key=int)
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15']
```

and in case you want a list of integers then

```
>>> sorted(map(int,chain(*b)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Speed comparison

```
>>> t1=Timer(stmt='sorted(map(int,chain(*b)))',setup='from __main__ import b;from itertools import chain')
>>> t2=Timer(stmt='sorted(int(i) for l in b for i in l)',setup='from __main__ import b')
>>> t3=Timer(stmt='sorted(int(a) for a in chain(*b))',setup='from __main__ import b;from itertools import chain')
>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t1.timeit(number=100000)/100000)
33.23 usec/pass
>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t2.timeit(number=100000)/100000)
35.60 usec/pass
>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t3.timeit(number=100000)/100000)
36.19 usec/pass
```

Comment: OP wanted a list of `int` objects.

Comment: @MattH:Sorry I missed that part.

Comment: but you're also importing itertools for t1&t3.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I didn;t get your concern. Does importing itertools hurts in any manner? If you see using `map`, even with the import overhead is faster.

Comment: No concerns now, actually `from itertools import chain` was not visible to me inside `Timer` until I scrolled.